# Expression issues (JSON) with power automate

Tags: json, api, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate

I'm working on power automate and I have an issue because I've tried a lot expressions and none of them working.

I did a loop (foreach) and inside a message (compose) and there I tried to display "f7626790-0756-43bf-a757-a645a33b853d" from"client"

To do so, I've tried all those expressions:

- item()?['client']
- item()?['client']?[0]
- item()['client']

[image]

Here my json file:

```
[
    {
        "gift": [
            {
                "client": "f7626790-0756-43bf-a757-a645a33b853d",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "client_id": 10859085,
                        "type": "christmas",
                        "application_id": "6e6d758d-8e74-3ae3-ac84-50eb23ae65f"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Show us your flow or provide the error you’re getting. You have a nested array, how many loops do you have?

Comment: I warn you that my flow is in French !
[flow][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzlDN.png

I don't have any error with "item()?['client']" but nothing it displays !

I have a sigle loop because I just want "client" !
Thanks !

Comment: Yes but your JSON has two arrays, you have one loop in your flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the JSON you provided, you have two arrays.  So the question for me is, which array do you want to iterate?  Both or the inner one?

I'm going to assume both or if not, it won't matter if you only ever have one item for both of them, my answer will still retrieve the `client` property.

[image: Result]

- The `Initialize Data` step has your JSON.
- The `Initialize Client` step is a blank string at this stage.
- The `For Each Outer Item` expression is simply a link to the `Data` variable as initialized in the first step.
- The `For Each Gift` expression is set as ... `item()?['gift']` ... as you can work out, that will loop over each `gift` item.
- Finally, I get the value of the `client` property using this expression ... `item()['client']`

Comment: Thanks "Skin" for your help, it was very useful to understand how the json works with loops ! !
Bye !

Comment: Can you flag it as the answer then? It rewards those who help and helps others with the same sort of question.